# iOS State restoration and UINavigationController modal views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to incorporate State Restoration in my app. I have it working fine for the most part, but presenting a navigation controller for a modal view on top of another navigation controller seems challenging.

For testing, I created a new split-view app on the iPad, with navigation controllers for both sides of the split view, and a Master and Detail view controller for each side, the roots of their respective navcontrollers. In the master view, you can click on a button to push a new TestViewController onto the navController stack programatically. I hook up the splitView in the storyboard, add restorationIDs to everything, opt-in to the delegate, provide a restoration class and adhere to the UIViewControllerRestoration protocol for TestViewController (since it's created programmatically) and everything works fine. If I close the app and retort it, it will start the TestViewController pushed onto the master's navcontroller. So far so good.

I then change the button handler to present the TestViewController inside a new UINavigationController, present it onto the master's navigation controller, to show a modal view (instead of pushing it on the nav stack). Now, when I relaunch the app, there is no modal view there anymore. TestModalViewController's viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:coder: is actually called correctly as before, but the modal view is never presented for some reason.

Here is the code for what I'm talking about

**MasterViewController.h:**

```
- (void)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    TestModalViewController *test = [[TestModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    test.restorationIdentifier = @"testid";
    test.restorationClass = [TestModalViewController class];

    UINavigationController *modal = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:test];
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    modal.restorationIdentifier = @"ModalTestID";
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:nil];
    return;
}
```

**TestModalViewController.m:**

```
+ (UIViewController *) viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents coder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    TestModalViewController *test = [[TestModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    test.restorationClass = [TestModalViewController class];
    test.restorationIdentifier = [identifierComponents lastObject];
    return test;
}
```

Perhaps the UINavigationController that is created to display modally is never preserved? Not sure why, because it does have a restorationIdentifier.

**Edit:**

After further testing, it turns out if I remove the UINavigationController from the the pushButton: code, and present the TestModalViewController instance directly, it gets restored correctly. So something about the UINavigationController being presented from another UINavigationController?

This works (though not what I really want):

```
- (void)pushButton:(id)sender
{
    TestModalViewController *test = [[TestModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    test.restorationIdentifier = @"testid";
    test.restorationClass = [TestModalViewController class];

    //UINavigationController *modal = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:test];
    //modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    //modal.restorationIdentifier = @"ModalTestID";
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:test animated:YES completion:nil];
    return;
}
```

**EDIT**:
Attached link to test project: [dropbox.com/sh/w8herpy2djjl1kw/vw_ZWqimgt](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w8herpy2djjl1kw/vw_ZWqimgt)

It's basically the Core Data master-detail template; run it on the iPad simulator. The + button in Master invokes the TestModalVC; if you then press the Home button, then kill debugger and launch again, you see the snapshot contains the TestModalVC but when the app is launched, it doesn't get restored

Comment: Can please attach a sample project?

Comment: Here's a link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w8herpy2djjl1kw/vw_ZWqimgt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create your own restoration class to handle this, or add the following to your app delegate:

```
- (UIViewController *)application:(UIApplication *)application viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:(NSArray *)identifierComponents
coder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSString *lastIdentifier = [identifierComponents lastObject];
    if ([lastIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ModalTestID"])
    {
        UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
        nc.restorationIdentifier = @"ModalTestID";
        return nc;
    }
    else if(...) //Other navigation controllers
    {
    }

    return nil;
}
```

More information in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application%3aviewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath%3acoder%3a).

Comment: Thanks. But if you look at the sample, TestModalViewController does have a restorationClass and a restorationIdentifier that is set. But UINavigationController doesn't seem to play by the same rules. Let me test if viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath will work

Comment: @ZS The problem is not `TestModalViewController`, it's the navigation controller. If you do not set a class, the system tries the last resort - the app delegate.

Comment: Thanks. That partially works; the only confusion is that this UIApplication viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath is queried for every restorationID; so if I'm returning nil for other identifiers (for e.g. the splitView, master view, detail view etc), I'm going to end up returning nil instead? How do I let it use the restoration class by default, and only default to this for UINavigationController? Or do I have to move ALL my code from the class's viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath: into this UIApplication delegate viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath:

Comment: @ZS Documentation states that "During state restoration, when UIKit encounters **a view controller without a restoration class**, it calls this method to ask for the corresponding view controller object." So the app delegate will only be called if you have not set a restoration class.

Comment: Thanks. This does work. Even though the UIApplication viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath *seems* to be called for every restorationID, even those with a restoration class defined (contrary to documentation), you can ignore the ones you have defined a restoration class (i.e. return nil), and it will eventually call the UIViewController's viewControllerWithRestorationIdentifierPath: to get the correct view controller